# Unable to install Nectari's BILicense Server software on Windows Server

Tags: database, sql

Trying to install the BILicense Service for Sage X3 SEI (Sage Enterprise Intelligence) on a Windows 2019 server.  This is a prerequisite before installing SEI for Sage X3.  Straight out of the gate it fails on a brand new windows server with:

```
  Error 27506. Error executing SQL script
  Create_SEI_DB. Line 25. CREATE DATABASE failed.
  Some file names listed could not be created. Check 
  related errors. (1802)
```

Doesn't matter if you use default or change paths and SQL login accounts.
SQL Server is on a different server than where the SEI server is being installed.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! [Server Fault is a site for information technology professionals](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) -- as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and as explained in our how-to [write a great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681)  one of those expectations is that when your error messages gives you an explicit instruction like `Check related errors. (1802)` ; you show evidence of  following that instruction... Also; don't be shy of contacting a vendors helpdesk when you have bought a license and suppport.

Comment: It was impossible to list ```Check related errors``` because there was no enumeration of what or where those errors were. There was nothing logged to a file or the event viewer to help with the error.  You don't even have access to the ```Create_SEI_DB``` SQL script mentioned in the error message. The vendor's helpdesk was consulted, there was nothing there of any help

Answer (score 1):

I used the SQL Server Profiler built into SSMS to capture the SQL the installer was trying to execute.  This provided the filesystem (default) paths and `CREATE DATABASE` command that it was trying to execute to troubleshoot the problem.

**Quick summary of the problem:**

SQL Server was trying to create the database, and put the database files (**BILicence.mdf** & **BILicence_log.ldf**) in `C:\Sage\SEI\BILicenseDB\` as I had specified during the installation. But the path didn't exist because the installer fails to create it before running the SQL code.  I think it is trying to create that path, but it must be delimited incorrectly in the installer code.

If you have spaces in your path, it creates bogus "**Program**", "**Files**", "**BILicense**" and a "**Database**" directories in incorrect places in the hierarchy, as if the spaces were causing the path parsing and subsequent path creation to go awry.  Even if there are no spaces, it doesn't work properly.  Using all of the defaults also fail.  It just plain doesn't work out of the box when the SEI server is remote from the database server.

Pre-creating the desired installation path **before** you run the installer DOES seem to work. For completeness, the path needs to be created on the **database** server, not the SEI server. The **BILicence.mdf** & **BILicence_log.ldf** files get put in that path by the SQL `CREATE DATABASE` command.

There seems to also be a dyslexic "**BILicense**" vs "**BILicence**" spelling variation that might be why the path creating is failing in the installer. To wit:

```
      Database name:                       BILicense
      Database pathname:                   BILicence Database
      Database filename (in SQL):          BILicence.mdf  &  BILicence_log.ldf
      Database filename (in filesystem):   BILicence.mdf  &  BILicence_log.ldf
      ALTER DATABASE name (in SQL):                          BILicense_log
```

Notice that the ALTER DATABASE line above seems to be wrong, and doesn't match the actual filesystem file name.

```
  --- SQL START ---
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'BILicense')
  IF @IS_REMOTE_SERVER_VAR <> '1'
      BEGIN
        CREATE DATABASE [BILicense]
        ON  PRIMARY 
        ( NAME = N'BILicence', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Sage\BILicense Database\BILicence.mdf' )
        LOG ON 
        ( NAME = N'BILicence_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Sage\BILicense Database\BILicence_log.ldf' , MAXSIZE = 4GB )
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        CREATE DATABASE [BILicense]
        COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
        ALTER DATABASE BILicense MODIFY FILE
        ( NAME = N'BILicense_log' , MAXSIZE = 4GB )
      END
   --- SQL END ---
```